# Identify form changes

Tags: vb.net

I have a winform with many controls: checkboxes, textboxes, etc.
When the form is closed, I want to know if changes were made (chekboxes changed state, text changed, etc.).
Is there an elegant and short way to do so (besides creating an event for each control at design time)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a Boolean variable declared and everytime something is modified you change its value:

```
Public bChanges As Boolean = False
```

In any control changed (managed with its events for example):

```
bChanges = True
```

And when the form is closed (declare the variable outside the forms class if you want it to exists later on) you can check its value easily.

You need to create the events to know if the controls are modified. You can group the events for this purpose:

```
Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
```

Or you can create the events dinamically looping for the form controls and determining the method you assign depending on the type of the control:

```
For Each elem As Control in Me.Controls
    AddHandler elem.TextChanged, AddressOf ChangedMethod
Next
```

Comment: How can I loop controls inside controls? I have groupboxes on my form

Comment: Every Control has the `.Controls` property with all the controls he has inside (he case he contains something).